# Not able to insert array value in database in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to i phone programming.I want to store array count and array objectAtindex value in database.But its not store can u tell me how can i store that

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[tapCollection1 objectAtIndex:i]);
 NSLog(@"%i",[array11 count]);

NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into Taukyblauky(taukyid,blaukyid) values (\"%\",\"%i\")",[tapCollection1 objectAtIndex:i],[array11 count]];
```

what is correct way to insert [tapCollection1 objectAtIndex:i] and [array11 count]

```
 Inside that  [tapCollection1 objectAtIndex:i] it contain some value like this 3.
 Inside that [array11 count] it contain some value like this 2.
```

what is correct way inserting objectAtindex value and array count value in database.
Thanks
Aslam

Comment: If you NSLog your insertSQL string you will see it's not as you expect.

Comment: once can u show value of insertSQL string?

Answer (score 0):

No, CoreData is an ORM. You don't write out queries (especially inserts). You should be able to just call save on it on the context.

Look at insertNewObjectForEntityName in NSEntityDescription, and then save on ManagedObjectContext.

Comment: Acctually i am using sqlite database.In sqlite how can i store?

Comment: Use CoreData, and look at some of the examples. Writing code like this in 2013 is absurd.